# How to stream byte array as body data in cpprest sdk?

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I am using C++ REST SDK to send a byte array to API service. I wrote a code like below but it didn't work out. I always getting 400 bad request error. How can i stream byte array as a body data in c++ restsdk?

```
auto postJson = pplx::create_task([param1, param2]() {

string params = "value1=" + param1+ "&value2=" + param2;
params = url_encode(params);     //encode the string otherwise it gives the error that provided uri is not invalid

wstring param(params.begin(), params.end());

http_client client(U("https://test.com/UploadServices/Service.svc"));
uri_builder builder(U("UploadFile?"+param));


vector<unsigned char> bytearray;       //vectorchar is the char vector of file
copy(vectorchar.begin(), vectorchar.end(), back_inserter(bytearray));    //converting char vector to unsigned char vector

http_request requestt(methods::POST);
requestt.set_request_uri(builder.to_string());
requestt.headers().set_content_type(L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
requestt.set_body(bytearray);   //set body parameter should be unsigned char


return client.request(requestt);
})

.then([](http_response response) {
       
        if (response.status_code() != 200) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Returned " + std::to_string(response.status_code()));
        }

        
        response.headers().set_content_type(L"application/json");
        return response.extract_json();
            })

        
                .then([](json::value jsonObject) {
                std::wcout << jsonObject.serialize().c_str() << endl;
                
                    });

            try {
                postJson.wait();


            }
            catch (const std::exception& e) {
                printf("Error exception:%s\n", e.what());
            }
}
```

In c# i did as below and it worked.

```
string params = "value1=" + param1+ "&value2=" + param2;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://test.com/UploadServices/Service.svc/UploadFile?"+ k);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);

Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = utfBytes.Length;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
  stream.Write(utfBytes, 0, utfBytes.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

How can i do the same thing with c++ restsdk? Thank you for your help.

Comment: could you not print the complete URL that is being sent to service by both these and see what is the difference?

Comment: If I can't compile your example, its really hard to help. Can you share a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: PS: 400 => is [Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses)

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to encode only one parameter, not the whole piece .